# Looking for distance between multiple points in a googlesheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```js
// adapted from developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros
function drivingDistance(origin, waypoint, destination) {
    var directions = getDirections_(origin, destination);
    return directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
}

function getDirections_(origin, waypoint, destination) {
    var directionFinder = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
    directionFinder.setOrigin(origin);
    directionFinder.addWaypoint(waypoint);
    directionFinder.setDestination(destination);

    var directions = directionFinder.getDirections();
    if (directions.routes.length == 0) {
    throw 'Unable to calculate directions between these addresses.';
    }
    return directions;
}
```

This script originally checked column A for origin and then checked column B for destination.  I was trying to use the addWaypoint function to add a 3rd point, but have been unsuccessful.  I read through the API and tried a few different variations, but am afraid that I was again unsuccessful. How do I add multiple destinations or waypoints

Comment: Did you try this example: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/direction-finder

Comment: I am asking for help regarding the code I posted, I appreciate the link but it's not what I am looking for.

Comment: if I were to remove the code "addWaypoint"  in my spreadsheet this script will find the difference between the 1st column in a range and the 2nd column in a range.  I can use the function to find the distance from a to b, b to c, c to d and so on, but that adds complexity to the sheet and slows it down.  I am trying to tell the script to look for 3 points instead of the 2.  Any help would be awesome as I am quite stuck.

Comment: Not sure I understand. What do you mean 3 point rather than 2. Do you mean several routes with the same starting point?

Comment: One origin two destinations along the same route.  but calculated in a google spreadsheet

Comment: You mean add 2 way points? Can you expand your question, I still don't understand.

Comment: The code that I posted is for a Google Spreadsheet the code does not work correctly, I would like it to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

When there are multiple waypoints, a `route` will consist of multiple `legs`, each of which has its own `distance`. So once you have the route calculated, you still need to go through each of the legs and sum up the individual distances to arrive at a final value.

Once we have this figured out for one mid-point, surely we'll want it for two. And once we have it for two, why not three? Finally, why not an arbitrary number of waypoints?

See [Accept Arbitrary Number of Arguments in Google Scripts Custom Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641791/accept-arbitrary-number-of-arguments-in-google-scripts-custom-function/27339268#27339268) for an example of how a custom function with arbitrary parameters will behave in a Spreadsheet.

This modified script handles a route with any number of points. It's fully supported by Auto-completion within Sheets. And it can handle a list of waypoints, or a range of cells. It's also copiously commented to explain each step.

Basic use:

```
=drivingDistance(A2:D2)
```

More advanced use, with a more understandable output:

```
=TEXT(drivingDistance(A2:D2)/1000,"#,### k\m")
```

[image: screenshot]

#### Code

Enough jabbering, just give me teh codez! (Updated code is available on [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/e07d537ff06f444866c5).)

```js
/**
 * Calculate the driving distance (in meters) along a route.
 *
 * @param {"london","manchester","liverpool"} route
 *        Comma separated ordered list of two or more map
 *        waypoints to include in route. First point
 *        is 'origin', last is 'destination'.
 *
 * @customfunction
 */
function drivingDistance(route) {
  // From gist.github.com/mogsdad/e07d537ff06f444866c5
  // Adapted from developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros
  // If a range of cells is passed in, 'route' will be a two-dimensional array.
  // Test for an array, and if we have one, collapse it to a single array.
  if (route.constructor === Array) {
    var args = route.join(',').split(',');
  }
  else {
    // No array? Grab the arbitrary arguments passed to the function.
    args = arguments;
  }
  
  // Just one rule to a route - we need a beginning and an end
  if (args.length < 2) throw new Error( "Must have at least 2 waypoints." )
  
  // Pass our waypoints to getDirections_(). Tricky bit, this.
  var directions = getDirections_.apply(this, args);

  // We have our directions, grab the first route's legs
  var legs = directions.routes[0].legs;
  
  // Loop through all legs, and sum up distances
  var dist = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<legs.length; i++) {
    dist += legs[i].distance.value;
  }
  
  // Done - return the value in meters
  return dist;
}

/**
 * Use Maps service to get directions for a route consisting of an arbitrary
 * set of waypoints.
 */
function getDirections_(route) {
  // Just one rule to a route - we need a beginning and an end
  if (arguments.length < 2) throw new Error( "Must have at least 2 waypoints." )
  
  // Assume first point is origin, last is destination.
  var origin = arguments[0];
  var destination = arguments[arguments.length-1];
  
  // Build our route; origin + all midpoints + destination
  var directionFinder = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  directionFinder.setOrigin(origin);
  for ( var i=1; i<arguments.length-1; i++ ) {
    directionFinder.addWaypoint(arguments[i]);
  }
  directionFinder.setDestination(destination);

  // Get our directions from Map service;
  // throw an error if no route can be calculated.
  var directions = directionFinder.getDirections();
  if (directions.routes.length == 0) {
    throw 'Unable to calculate directions between these addresses.';
  }
  return directions;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A parameter was missing in `function drivingDistance()`. I changed

```js
var directions = getDirections_(origin, destination);
```

to

```js
var directions = getDirections_(origin, waypoint, destination);
                                        ^^^^^^^^
```

Here's the updated code, with a test function

```js
function testDistance() {
 var dist = drivingDistance("london","manchester","liverpool");
 Logger.log( dist );   // 321563 (meters)
}

function drivingDistance(origin, waypoint, destination) {
    var directions = getDirections_(origin, waypoint, destination);
    return directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
}

function getDirections_(origin, waypoint, destination) {
    var directionFinder = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
    directionFinder.setOrigin(origin);
    directionFinder.addWaypoint(waypoint);
    directionFinder.setDestination(destination);

    var directions = directionFinder.getDirections();
    if (directions.routes.length == 0) {
      throw 'Unable to calculate directions between these addresses.';
    }
    return directions;
}
```

Good luck with this. Learning how to program takes time. I suggest you find a website that teaches Java Script. Hope you get it working with the spreadsheet.

PS: If you'd like a more readable result, you could change the last line of `drivingDistance()` to give `distance.text` instead of `distance.value`. In the London-Manchester-Liverpool example, the result would be `"322 km"`.

Comment: + For figuring out what the question actually was! Hope you don't mind that I tweaked your answer a bit. Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately, because the question wasn't clear to start with, this answer doesn't address the "correctness" problem. Because of the additional midpoint, the original code doesn't consider the existence of multiple legs on the journey - so it returns only the distance of the first leg.